# A sequence that converges almost everywhere but not in the norm of $L^p (X, \mu).$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Then we can see that $ \{ f_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges almost everywhere but not in the norm of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, we know that if $X$ is a finite measure space, then converges almost everywhere implies convergence in measure. My question is, can we somehow restrict $X = \mathbb{R}$ in the example above to a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(E) < \infty$ so we get that $ \{ f_n \} $ converges in measure but not in the norm of $L^p(E)$?

Ultimately I am wanting to find an example of a sequence that converges in measure but not in the norm of $L^p(X, \mu)$.

Comment: What about $E= [0,1], \mu$ the Lebesgue measure restricted to the interval and $f_n= n \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with your notation. Is $1_{[0, 1/n ]}$ the same thing as $\chi_{[0, 1/n ]}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not  mentioning it.

Comment: no worries. Also, is this an example for $p = 1$?

Comment: ohh interesting! Let me see if I can make the argument for $p = 1$ at least.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the answer: this seems to work for $p \geq 1$

Comment: Can you show me the $p = 1$ case then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134200/discussion-between-foe-and-emmak).